# GWT Chart API googlecode, How to set RoleType to a column of a DataTable

Tags: gwt, google-visualization

I want to set a column RoleType in a column of a DataTable of GWT com.googlecode.gwt.charts.client to "certainty" but it seems there is no method to set it.  There is only method to access it. How do I set it?

I try to write manual set method with JSNI but doesn't seem to work.
    dataTable.addColumn(ColumnType.BOOLEAN);
        dataTable.setColumnProperty(4, "Certainty", false);

Answer (score 1):

I simply extended DataTable and added this method:

```
public final native int addCertaintyColumn()/*-{
     return this.addColumn({type:'boolean',role:'certainty'});
     }-*
/;
```

Then, when adding data, set true or false on this column(s)

Answer (score 0):

Roles still seem to be "experimental" and I couldn't find an issue/ticket

http://code.google.com/p/google-visualization-api-issues/issues/list?can=2&q=DataType+roles&colspec=ID+Type+Status+Priority+Milestone+Owner+Summary+Stars&cells=tiles

Would be nice to have I agree.

I am not sure if you are able to override the native methods of DataTable to add:
addColumn(type, role, param...)
right now you just have type and no roles :(

Answer (score 0):

I think DataColumn.setRole() should be used, to specify the role explicitly:

```
DataColumn col = DataColumn.create(ColumnType.BOOLEAN);
col.setRole(RoleType.CERTAINTY);
dataTable.addColumn(col);
```

However, also this does not work for me either. It gives me following error:

```
(Error) @com.googlecode.gwt.charts.client.DataTable::addColumn(Lcom/googlecode/gwt/charts/client/DataColumn;)([JavaScript object(110832)]): Invalid type: function() {
      var result = __static(dispId, this);
      if (result[0]) {
        throw result[1];
      } else {
        return result[1];
      }
    }
```

Comment: I forgot to say that I use gwt-charts, the unofficial Google Chart Tools API for Google Web Toolkit. Google Visualization-api does not have this setRole operation.